# Mousewheel Sliding like Apple 5s page

Tags: jquery, html, web, mousewheel, sliding

I'm new to jQuery & Javascript and I'm trying to remake the Apple 5s sliding page as you can see here: http://www.apple.com/iphone-5s/ . I'm quite far at the moment, but it doesn't stop calling the function when you rapidly scroll. What I mean by that, if you scroll down really fast with my code you basically get to the lowest slide. But at Apple its site the slide animation has to be finished before you can call the animation again. I'm having problems with realizing this. Here is my code.

HTML:

```
<div id="slider">
    <div id="slide1"></div>
    <div id="slide2"></div>
    <div id="slide3"></div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
// jQuery for Sliding
$(document).ready(function() {
    var scroll = 1;
    var currentScroll = 1;
    var totalSlides = $("#slider").children().length;
    $("#slider").children().hide();
    $("#slide1").show();
    $(window).bind('mousewheel', function(event) {
        if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta >= 0) {
            // Scroll event up
            currentScroll = scroll;
            scroll = scroll - 1;
            if (scroll < 1) { 
                scroll = 1;
            } 
            else { 
                $("#slide" + currentScroll).hide("slide", {
                    direction : 'down'
                }, 700);
                $("#slide" + scroll).show("slide", {
                    direction : 'up'
                }, 700);
            }

        } else {
            // Scroll event down
            currentScroll = scroll;
            scroll++;
            if (scroll < totalSlides + 1) {
                $("#slide" + currentScroll).hide("slide", {
                    direction : 'up' 
                }, 700); 
                $("#slide" + scroll).show("slide", { 
                    direction : 'down'
                }, 700);  
            } 
        } 
    }); 
});
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you try looking at the code on Apple's page to see what it's doing differently?

Comment: you can try something like this [http://jsfiddle.net/rv89x/](http://jsfiddle.net/rv89x/) add a variable and change it while you are showing the next slide then return to the default value

Comment: Spontaneously, I feel that you should prevent the function to be called multiple times during the same animation. What happens if you add a global variable `isScrolling=false;` that you then set to true at the start of the event and false at the end? If isScrolling is already true when the event triggers you should merely return out of the function without additional scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Apple's page, it's not hiding/showing the slides it's just anchoring it to a fix point (which is the slides `offset().top` position) depending on mousewheel direction. Binding `'mousewheel'` alone does not work on other browsers like firefox, it should be `'mousewheel DOMMouseScroll'`. Furthermore 'mousewheel-down' on firefox returns a positive value on chrome it's negative value.

This should be the mousewheel event structure, cross-browser-wise:

```
$(window).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var delta = e.originalEvent.detail < 0 || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 ? 1 : -1;

    if(delta < 0) { 
        //mousewheel down
    }else{
        //mousewheel up
    }
});
```

We need to determine which slide is currently being anchored, we can add a class 'active' as the indicator. If the user's mousewheel direction is down, move to the `next()` slide and reassign the class 'active' on this slide. If the user user's mousewheel direction is up, move to the `prev()` slide of the current 'active' slide and reassign the 'active' class.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(window).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();      
    var delta = e.originalEvent.detail < 0 || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 ? 1 : -1;
    //get the current active slide
    var $active = $('#slider > .active');

    if(delta < 0) { 
        //mousewheel down
        var $next = $active.next();
        //check if there's a next slide available
        if($next.length){
            //animate scrolling to the next slides offset top
           $('body, html').stop(true).animate({scrollTop:$next.offset().top},'slow');
           //move also the indicator class 'active'
           $next.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        }

    }else{
        //mousewheel up
        var $prev = $active.prev();
        if($prev.length){
             //animate scrolling to the previous slides offset top
            $('body, html').stop(true).animate({scrollTop:$prev.offset().top},'slow'); 
            $prev.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        }
    }
});  
});
```

See this [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/6ssRA/1/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mark. One problem is still there though. I want to check it per scroll, so it doesnt scroll down to the bottom when you do a fast scroll down/up. Especially for touchpads it scroll down even when you do it slowly, thats what i'm trying to fix. It should be when the animation is done then check for next scrolls.

Comment: @user3072335 That's a bit tricky and in this case would be related with the touch event and not the mousewheel. You can take a look at other implementation such as the one of [fullpage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/blob/master/jquery.fullPage.js). In that case a timeout is used with `setTimeout`. Another option would be using a timers, such as [OnePageScroll](https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll/blob/master/jquery.onepage-scroll.js) : `if(timeNow - lastAnimation < quietPeriod + settings.animationTime) {`